# jQuery Mobile size is too small, not able to work properly in device

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jQuery Mobile in PhoneGap. It is working fine in all browsers, but in mobile the view is very small.

I have used

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

in my html page, but then it is also very small.

Answer (score 2):

just try

```
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
enclose the below element in you head part.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

You can find the below details in the following page.

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/pages/